# A car goes through a line with length L in T seconds. Its intial velocity and final velocity are zero. Prove the following inequality.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $f(t)$ is position of the car at time $t$ (suppose that acceleration of the car is continuous part by part): $$\int_0^T f''(t)(\frac {T}{2} - t) \;\mathrm{dt} \le \max |f''| \frac {T^2}{4}$$

That means the result of integration is always less than or equal to the maximum magnitude of acceleration of the car during its movement, multiply to $\frac {T^2}{4}$. How do I prove this?

Things I did:
I know the result of integration is $$\left[f'(t)(\frac {T}{2}-t)+ f(t)\right]_0^T$$ which equals L . But I don't know how it's less than of equal to $\max |f''| \frac {T^2}{4}$ .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^T {{f}^{\prime\prime}}(t) (\frac T2 - t) dt &\le \left|\int_0^T {{f}^{\prime\prime}}(t) (\frac T2 - t) dt\right|  \\
&\le \int_0^T\left| {{f}^{\prime\prime}}(t) (\frac T2 - t) \right| dt \\
&\le \int_0^T \max \left|{f}^{\prime\prime}\right| \left|\left(\frac T2 - t\right)\right| dt \\
&=\max |f^{\prime\prime}| \int_0^T \left|\frac{T}{2}-t\right| dt \\
&=\max |f^{\prime\prime}| \left(\int_0^{\frac T2} \left(\frac{T}{2}-t\right) dt + \int_{\frac T2}^T \left(t-\frac{T}{2}\right) dt\right) \\
&=\max |f^{\prime\prime}| \frac{T^2}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$